# CMake: Linking a static library (.a) to small c++ script

Tags: cmake

I am trying to link a prebuilt static library, leveldb,  to a small c++ script however I am getting a file not found error when trying to include the .h file from the lib. I don't know CMake that well so any help is appreciated.

```cpp
//script.cc
#include <iostream>
#include "leveldb/db.h" // <<<<<<<< " fatal error: leveldb/db.h: No such file or directory"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  std::cout << "hello \n";
  return 0;
}
```

As per other stack overflow posts static linking is done with target_link_libraries().
This is my current cmake file
CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4)
project(my_project)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/)
add_executable(runscript script.cc)
target_link_libraries(runscript ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/libleveldb.a)
```

this is essentially what my project directory looks like

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── script.cc
└── third_party
    └── libleveldb.a
```

Comment: So where is `db.h` file?

Comment: it should be apart of the static lib right?, look at the first code snippet from the github [link](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/master/doc/index.md)

Comment: No. That is literally the whole repo. Why not just include the cmake config?

Comment: I have no clue how to do that, do you know any stackoverflow posts for that?

Comment: also is there any reason why linking the static library wouldn't allow me to #include leveldb/db.h  ?

Comment: I believe just clone the repo, [add_subdirectory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/add_subdirectory.html) the cmake config, and then only `target_link_libraries(runscript PUBLIC leveldb)`. `.a` file are just object files, they do not contain headers. There is __no__ reason in that linking with a static library should add a path to the search path of includes and spawn files in there. Static library is just an archive of object files. Header files need to be shipped separately.

Comment: it worked. thank you! @KamilCuk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link with another `cmake` project, usually the way is to:

- Clone the repo somewhere. For example, if your project is meant to be under git control, most people add the third_party repos as git submodules. Note: that is also [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html).
- Then add `add_subdirectory(the_dir_with_the_repo)`. This will source the third_party CMakeLists.txt file and include all the targets that are there.
- After it, you can just `target_link_libraries(runscript PUBLIC leveldb)` use the targets from the third_party CMakeLists.txt like your own.

A static library, a file with `.a` extension, is just a archive of object files, that's all. Object files do not contain the information from header files, function declarations, external variables declarations, macros, etc. In C language headers are meant to be shipped separately, as entirely independent files.

Answer (score 1):

Solution. (Thanks to KamilCuk's comment above)
CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4)
project(my_proj)
add_subdirectory(third_party/leveldb)
add_executable(runscript script.cc)
target_link_libraries(runscript PUBLIC leveldb)
```

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── script.cc
└── third_party
    └── [leveldb repo]
```

Comment: Just `add_subdirectory(third_party/leveldb)`